# Adding a game over scene

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I want to add this game over scene to this game that I am trying to do for my homework, and I seem  to not have it where if you kill the target the game over scene will pop up. I tried putting my code in every line and see if it will finally work but no it didn't. So now I have to ask for some help.

. m file

```
  - (void)addTarget10 {
 Boss *target10 = nil;    
 if ((arc4random() % 2) == 0) {{
    target10 = [WeakAndFastBoss9 boss9];
     }}  else {
    target10 = [WeakAndFastBoss9 boss9];
    }                      
 [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"lastboss.mp3"];        
 // Determine where to spawn the target along the Y axis
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
int minY = target10.contentSize.height/2;
int maxY = winSize.height - target10.contentSize.height/2;
int rangeY = maxY - minY;
int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;
// Create the target slightly off-screen along the right edge,
// and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above
target10.position = ccp(winSize.width + (target10.contentSize.width/2), actualY);
[self addChild:target10 ];
// Determine speed of the target
int minDuration = target10.minMoveDuration;
int maxDuration = target10.maxMoveDuration;
int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;
// Create the actions
       id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration position:ccp(-       target10.contentSize.width/2, actualY)];
      id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self 
                                         selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished9:)];
[target10 runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];

target10.tag = 1;
[_targets addObject:target10];   
}
 -(void)gameLogicboss9:(ccTime)dt {


[self unschedule:_cmd];    



[self addTarget10];
  }

    - (void)updateboss9:(ccTime)dt {
CGRect projectileRect = CGRectMake(projectile.position.x - (projectile.contentSize.width/2), 
                                   projectile.position.y - (projectile.contentSize.height/2), 
                                   projectile.contentSize.width, 
                                   projectile.contentSize.height);

BOOL bossHit = FALSE;
NSMutableArray *targetsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


for (CCSprite *target1 in _targets) {
    CGRect target1Rect = CGRectMake(target1.position.x - (target1.contentSize.width/2), 
                                    target1.position.y - (target1.contentSize.height/2), 
                                    target1.contentSize.width, 
                                    target1.contentSize.height);


    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(projectileRect, target1Rect)) {

        [targetsToDelete addObject:target1];    
        bossHit = TRUE;
       Boss *boss = (Boss *)target1;
       boss.hp--;
       if (boss.hp <= 0  ) {
            [targetsToDelete addObject:target1];
            }
        break;

    }                       
}

for (CCSprite *target in targetsToDelete) {
    [_targets removeObject:target];

    [self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];                                  


     _projectilesDestroyed++;
    if (_projectilesDestroyed > 2) {


    }
}

if (bossHit) {
    //[projectilesToDelete addObject:projectile];

}
  [targetsToDelete release];



 }

  -(void)spriteMoveFinishedboss9:(id)sender {
CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)sender;
[self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];




if (sprite.tag == 1) { // target
    [_targets removeObject:sprite];





} else if (sprite.tag == 2) { // projectile





    [_projectiles removeObject:sprite];
    }     }
```

This the game over scene I want to add when target 10/ boss 9 is killed

```
GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene node];
[gameOverScene.layer.label setString:@"You Lose"];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameOverScene];
```

Right now my other game over scene is when the sprite is moved passed screen.If you need me to  answer any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: "I tried putting my code in every line and see if it will finally work" <= I think there's a name for that, but it's definitely not "programming". If you catch yourself doing that, stop. Step back. Take a break. Come back later. Take another look at your code. Step through it with the debugger. Learn what happens, try to figure out why it happens. FWIW, the code to replace the scene seems correct. Is it actually called? Have you set a breakpoint or added a NSLog to confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For scene replace you try this for your game code..

First Add this code to your GameOverScene class

```
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    GameOverScene *layer = [GameOverScene node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
```

Make your GameOverClass is subclass of CCLayer,
Than when You want to change scene do this

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[GameOverScene scene]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have to create a new scene. This can simple be done using File->New File and make it a subclass of NSObject. You then change the subclass to an CCLayer. As a test, you can just copy your code from the hello world layer. Next, just import  the new class in your helloworld layer class and create a instance of it. Then in a method use [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:sceneName];

You can use this site for more info, its very helpful, just read through it and you will find your answer:http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial